# How to create a reverse DNS record with SoftLayer api?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Wandering how to do it in java.
Example in other language would be helpful too.
Looked at api docs and java-client docs. 
Somewhat helpful was this, but that does not show how what is required content of data:
http://softlayer-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/SoftLayer/managers/dns.html#DNSManager.create_record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a php example https://gist.github.com/softlayer/815278
Maybe it's possible to do something similar with java client.